# Strapi : Add element in chid collection

Tags: rest, strapi

I have two collection type Organizations and Employees. 
Its a one to many relationship between Organization and Employee.

I want to add new employee in organization through rest api call in strapi.

Strapi doesn't provide :

```
http://localhost:1337/organizations/{id}/employees
```

How to do the update?

Answer (score 0):

There is no already built in solution to do it.

But in Strapi you can create your own controller to match that route and handle all the logic needed in there.

You can check the info about custom controllers [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#concept)

Answer (score 0):

As Christian said, you will have to create your own route in your Organization API.

1. Create your route.

**Path —** `api/organization/config/routes.json`

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/organizations/:id/employees",
      "handler": "organization.cusom",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

2. Create the controller function.

To do so, I will copy the function from the default `create` one:

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#core-controllers

**Path —** `api/organization/controllers/organizaion.js``

```js
const { parseMultipartData, sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  async custom(ctx) {
    let entity;
    if (ctx.is('multipart')) {
      const { data, files } = parseMultipartData(ctx);
      entity = await strapi.services.employee.create(data, { files });
    } else {
      entity = await strapi.services.employee.create(ctx.request.body);
    }
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.employee });
  },
};
```

And set `employee` for the creation cause we want to create employee.

3. Force to use the right organization ID

```js
module.exports = {
  async custom(ctx) {
    // get the id params from the URL
    const {id} = ctx.params;
    // force the relation to this specific organisation
    ctx.request.body.organization = id;

    if (ctx.is('multipart')) {
      const { data, files } = parseMultipartData(ctx);
      entity = await strapi.services.employee.create(data, { files });
    } else {
      entity = await strapi.services.employee.create(ctx.request.body);
    }
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.employee });
  },
};
```